# Cannot read property 'stringuid' of undefined: AGORAIO

Tags: reactjs, agora.io

While trying to make a live streaming platform, Agora gives the following error when I try to publish a stream.

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringUid' of undefined
    at Object.B.t._publish (AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:14)
    at Object.B.t.publish (AgoraRTCSDK.min.js:14)
    at e.<anonymous> (agora.js:141)
    at d (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:293)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:118)
    at r (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at s (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
```

The same code works just fine when testing on localhost, but gives this error when I try to access the same URL at the hosted website. The hosting environment is firebase.

Also, this was given in the agora [docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/console_error_web). Where they said:

> Reason
> You have called Stream.publish before the Client.join method call succeeds.
> Solution
> Check your code logic and ensure that you call Stream.publish after the Client.join method call succeeds.

But I have ensured that this is not the case by the use of debuggers.

EDIT: (code)

```
    async init( ) {
        if(!this.client) this.createClient();

        this.client.setClientRole(this.role);

        return new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => this.client.init(this.appID, resolve, reject)
        );
    }

    async attach( channel, uid = null, token ) {
        await this.init();

        return new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => this.client.join( token, channel, uid, resolve, reject )
        );
    }

    async join( channel, uid = null, token = null ) {
        this.role = 'audience';

        token = token ?? (await api.agora.token.get(channel)).token;
        console.log(token);
        this.uid = await this.attach(channel, uid, token);
        
        this.setAudienceEvents();
    }

    async host(channel, uid = null, token = null) {
        this.role = 'host';

        this.uid = await this.attach(channel, uid, token ?? this.token); // joining channel

        let stream = await this.createStream(uid);

        await this.enableDualStream();
        this.client.publish(stream, errFn); // publishing
        this.client.setRemoteVideoStreamType(stream, 0);

        this.setHostEvents();
    }

    async createStream( uid, config = defaults.stream) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if(!this.client) this.createClient();
            this.uid = this.stream? this.stream.getId(): uid;

            if(this.stream) this.removeStream();

            let options = _.pick(config, [ 'video', 'audio', 'screen' ]);
            let stream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
                streamID: this.uid,
                ...options
            });

            stream.setVideoProfile(config.resolution);
            stream.init(( ) => resolve(stream), reject);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Can you add your code snippet where you call `Stream.publish`. This error does not tell much as it is generated from obfuscated code.

Answer (score 0):

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringUid' of undefined**

this error means that you have to pass

uid as string "123"

e.g
this.uid = stringUid.tosting()

and always create new uid for publish and subscriber case and second always use
new token for publish and subscriber. Please check from official documentation
https://docs.agora.io/en/search/Interactive%20Broadcast?platform=Web